# I'm a tricky word puzzle

Tags: riddle, word, letters

**Instructions:**

Look at the sentences. For each sentence, look for a one-word solution. Then take the first letter of those words to make the answer to the riddle.

**Example:**

> A huge animal = *Elephant*
>    I won't touch it because it's _____ = *Gross*
>    Which ___ was that boy talking to? = *Girl*
>
> **E**lephant + **G**ross + **G**irl = **EGG**.

**Riddle:**

We're the first people you saw.

One of UK's mythical animals.

I dazzle predators with patterns.

I rhyme with teal.

I'm a dangerous feline.

You eat me with bacon and toast.

Comment: To answer, read the examples carefully

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> PUZZLE.

*We're the first people you saw.*

> **P**arents.

*One of UK's mythical animals.*

> **U**nicorn.

*I dazzle predators with patterns.*

> **Z**ebra.

*I rhyme with teal.*

> **Z**eal.

*I'm a dangerous feline.*

> **L**ion.

*You eat me with bacon and toast.*

> **E**ggs.